# Sqrt' in Mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, derivative

I was taking a derivative in Mathematica and  the result containted the term `Sqrt'`, and I was wondering what the `'` on the end ment? I believe in means `1/Sqrt` from doing the derivative by hand but if someone could confirm this is how the result is displayed I would appreciate it. Here is my input and output.

```
 In    f[p_] := cSqrt[(m^2)*(c^2) + (p - eA/c)^2] + e*phi
 In    f'[p]
 Out    2 (-(eA/c) + p) Derivative[1][cSqrt][c^2 m^2 + (-(eA/c) + p)^2]
```

Best,
Ben

Comment: You probably mean `c*Sqrt`, rather than `cSqrt` in your input.

Comment: Wow good eye, you nailed it! I stared at that for a while and did not notice the problem, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help:
http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/05/20/mathematica-qa-three-functions-for-computing-derivatives/

Apparently ' is the standard shorthand notation for the derivative.